# Error "Can't set headers after they are sent" when redirecting

Tags: javascript, node.js

i have this code:

```js
const http = require('http');

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  const url = req.url;
      
  if(url == "/")
  {
    new Main(req, res).index()
  }
  else if(url == "/login")
  {
    new Main(req, res).login()
  }
});

server.listen(8000)

class Main
{
  constructor(req, res)
  {
    this.req = req;
    this.res = res;
    
    if(true && this.req.url != "/login")
    //   ^ not important variable
    {
      this.res.statusCode = 302;
      this.res.setHeader('Location', '/login')
      this.res.end()
    }
  }
  index()
  {
    this.res.statusCode = 200;
    this.res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
    this.res.write('Index');
    this.res.end()
  }
  login()
  {
    this.res.statusCode = 200;
    this.res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
    this.res.write('Login');
    this.res.end()
  }
}
```

It must check if user isn't authorize, it redirect it to "/login"

but, when it redirecting it throw this error "Can't set headers after they are sent".
Is there anauther way to redirectin in node js?

Comment: You are doing the redirect in the constructor function, but then also calling `index()`, ie `Main(...).index()` there is no condition here to check to see if you need to call `index()` or not

Comment: In fact, not calling `login()`, but `index()`, where the header is set again ... triggering the error.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are send response back to caller multiple times. To make it easy to understand lets take an example:

```
function main() {
    ...statement1;
     return true;  // Will return when reach here
    // Will never reach hear as already returned;
    ...statement2;
    return false; // Since already returned thus will never come here;
}
```

This is self explaining, statement2 is never reached as already returned. Let's use res function in place of return:

```
function main() {
    ...statement1;
    res.send(true);  // Will call function res.send() and continue processing
    // Will be here as function didn't returned and thus after calling one function main function continue execution
    ...statement2;
    res.send(false); // will call another function
}
```

As res.send(), res.write(), res.end() and other res functions are just function calling so execution doesn't stop and continue calling. However `res.send()`, `res.end()`, `res.json()` all end connection from request source and send back response to request source. Thus calling these function again will generate error as connection is already closed and response is send back to request and you can't change one response once it's send.

Why this has happened in your code is due to sending back response and ending connection with request source in your constructor and then trying to send back another response to closed connection.

```
class Main
{
  constructor(req, res)
  {
    this.req = req;
    this.res = res;

    if(true && this.req.url != "/login")
    //   ^ not important variable
    {
      this.res.statusCode = 302;
      this.res.setHeader('Location', '/login')
      this.res.end() // Response is send back and ended connection with request source.
    }
  }
  index()
  {
    this.res.statusCode = 200;
    this.res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
    this.res.write('Index');
    this.res.end()
  }
  login()
  {
    this.res.statusCode = 200;
    this.res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
    this.res.write('Login');
    this.res.end()
  }
}
```

When creating new object of class it's constructor is called, here constructor is:

```
constructor(req, res)
  {
    this.req = req;
    this.res = res;

    if(true && this.req.url != "/login")
    //   ^ not important variable
    {
      this.res.statusCode = 302;
      this.res.setHeader('Location', '/login')
      this.res.end() // Response is send back and ended connection with request source.
    }
  }
```

As you can see in case of `req.url` not being `login` you ended the connection and thus only getting error when again called `login()` as `login()` is sending response back to closed connection.

```
new Main(req, res); // Calling constructor.

new Main(req, res).login(); // Calling constructor first then calling login function
```

As login function is:

```
  login()
  {
    this.res.statusCode = 200;
    this.res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
    this.res.write('Login');
    this.res.end()   // Sending response to request source
  }
```

To solve issue here all you need to do is not return and end connection in your constructor:

```
class Main
{
  constructor(req, res)
  {
    this.req = req;
    this.res = res;

    if(true && this.req.url != "/login")
    //   ^ not important variable
    {
      this.res.statusCode = 302;
      this.res.setHeader('Location', '/login')
    }
  }
  index()
  {
    this.res.statusCode = 200;
    this.res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
    this.res.write('Index');
    this.res.end()
  }
  login()
  {
    this.res.statusCode = 200;
    this.res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
    this.res.write('Login');
    this.res.end()
  }
}
```

This is one solution as per your current coding style, you should try to implement a better architecture and use a better framework to maintain API and routing.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, but it did not solve my problem. Now "Router" does not redirect.

Comment: use `res.redirect()`